# A subcontinuous function, which is not continuous

Tags: banach-spaces, counterexamples, continuity

> Let $E$ be a Banach space and $T: E\rightarrow E$ be a mapping. $T$ is  said to be *subcontinuous* if for any sequences $(u_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ in $E$ that converge strongly to $u$ the sequence $(T(u_n))_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges weakly to $T(u)$.

I am looking for a subcontinuous function which is not continuous. I thought I can find something in $l^2$, but I didn't.

*I already posted it on math.stackexchange, but to no avail*

Thank you

Comment: Link to the Math SE post (from 9 months ago): https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3393342/279515

Comment: I delete it, since i didn't have any interaction on Math SE..

Comment: Maybe you could have instead provided a community wiki answer there linking to the accepted answer here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let $(e_n)$ be the standard orthonormal basis of $\ell^2$: recall that, as a sequence, $(e_n)$ converges weakly to $0$.  Now define a map $f\colon\mathbb{R} \to \ell^2$ by $f(\frac{1}{n})=e_n$ and $f(t)=0$ if $t\leq 0$, and interpolating linearly between $\frac{1}{n}$ and $\frac{1}{n+1}$: this is continuous at every point except at $0$ where it is subcontinuous (because any sequence of the form $t_k\, e_{n_k} + (1-t_k)\, e_{n_k+1}$ with $0\leq t_k\leq 1$ and $n_k\to+\infty$, converges weakly to $0$ when $k\to+\infty$).  If you want a subcontinuous function $\ell^2\to\ell^2$, just right-compose $f$ with a nonzero continuous linear map $\ell^2\to\mathbb{R}$, e.g., $e_0^*$.

Comment: What the you mean exactly by : *interpolating linearly between...*

Comment: That  means if $x\in[(n+1]^{-1},n^{-1}]$ then $$f(x) = f(\frac1n) +(f(\frac1{n+1}) -f(\frac1n))\frac{x-\frac1n}{\frac1{n+1} - \frac1n} $$

Comment: The sequence $u_k$ must be general (and converges to $0$), I don't know why you assume that $0\leq u_k\leq 1$?

Comment: What I called $u_k$ obviously wasn't what was called $u_k$ in the question: I changed this to $t_k$ to avoid confusion. Terms with $u_k<0$ are unproblematic, all terms will be $\leq 1$ eventually, and terms between $0$ and $1$ can be written $t/n+(1-t)/(n+1)$ with $0\leq t\leq 1$ so their image by $f is $te_n+(1-t)e_{n+1}$.